# Updating value - SwiftyJSON

Tags: ios, json, swift

I have a json object as below

```
{"level" :{"currentLevel":"1","score":"100"}}
```

I have this json data in my project folder and I am using SwiftyJSON to parse my son and read the values. Everything looks fine.

Now I need to update the score and I am trying as below

```
var json = JSON({"level" :{"currentLevel":"1","score":"100"}})
json["level"]["score"] = "200"
```

This works fine too and the json is updated but below try fails

```
var json = JSON({"level" :{"currentLevel":"1","score":"100"}})
var updatedScore:String = "200"
json["level"]["score"] = updatedScore
```

I get compile error

```
Type [Subscript] does not conform to Protocol 'StringLiteralConvertible'
```

Any suggestion on how to update a SwiftJSON JSON object with a variable would be helpful

Thank you

Update:My Solution

This is what I have done finally

```
    var json = JSON({"level" :{"currentLevel":"1","score":"100"}})
    var level = (json["level"] as JSON).dictionaryObject
    let updatedScore = "200"
    level!["currentLevel"] = updatedScore
    json["level"] = JSON(level!)
```

And this works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the below if you are saving the json as dictionary

```
((json["level"]as nsdictionary)["score"] as NSString = updatedScore)
```